# How to mock the same function called in different components with different returned values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I need to mock a function `useAxios` but this is called in two different components, and one of these components is used inside the other. This is my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import useAxios from 'axios-hooks'
import { Table, Space } from 'antd'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faEdit, faCalendar, faUserPlus, faTimes } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

export const RemoveProjectButton = ({ project, updateProjects }) => {
  const [, execute] = useAxios(
    {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/projects/${project.key}/`,
      method: 'delete'
    },
    {
      manual: true
    }
  )
  const removeProject = async (project) => {
    await execute()
    updateProjects(project)
  }

  return <a data-testid={`project-${project.key}`} onClick={() => { removeProject(project) }}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} /></a>
}

export const Projects = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
  const [{ data, loading, error }] = useAxios(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/projects/`
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    setProjects(data)
  }, [data])

  useEffect(() => {}, [projects])

  const updateProjects = (projectToDelete) => {
    setProjects(() => projects.filter(project => project.key !== projectToDelete.key))
  }

  if (loading) return <p data-testid='loading'>Loading...</p>
  if (error) return <p data-testid='error'>Error!</p>

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'Title',
      dataIndex: 'title',
      key: 'title',
      render: title => <a>{title}</a>
    },
    {
      title: 'Start Date',
      dataIndex: 'startDate',
      key: 'startDate'
    },
    {
      title: 'Description',
      dataIndex: 'description',
      key: 'description',
      render: description => `${description.substring(0, 50)}...`
    },
    {
      title: 'Team',
      dataIndex: 'team',
      key: 'team'
    },
    {
      title: 'Action',
      key: 'action',
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Space size='middle'>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCalendar} />
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserPlus} />
          <RemoveProjectButton project={record} updateProjects={updateProjects} />
        </Space>
      )
    }
  ]

  return (
    <Table
      data-testid='project-table'
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={projects}
      pagination={false}
    />
  )
}
```

and this is my test:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Projects, RemoveProjectButton } from '../Projects'
import useAxios from 'axios-hooks'
jest.mock('axios-hooks')

const TABLE_TEST_ID = 'project-table'
const fakeData = [
  {
    key: 1,
    title: 'Testing Project Alpha',
    startDate: '2020-04-18',
    description: 'This is just for testing',
    team: 'A, B, C'
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    title: 'Testing Project Beta',
    startDate: '2020-04-19',
    description: 'This is just for testing too',
    team: 'X, Y, Z'
  }
]

describe('projects table', () => {
  let projects

    beforeEach(() => {
      projects = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fakeData))
      useAxios.mockReturnValue([{
        data: projects,
        loading: false,
        error: null
      }])
    })

    it('removes project when clicking on X button in row', async () => {
      const { getByTestId, queryByTestId } = render(<Projects />)
      const executeMock = jest.fn()

      useAxios.mockReturnValue([{
        data: projects,
        loading: false,
        error: null
      }])
      .mockReturnValue([{}, executeMock])
      .mockReturnValue([{}, executeMock])



      expect(getByTestId(TABLE_TEST_ID)).toHaveTextContent('Testing Project Alpha')
      await fireEvent.click(getByTestId('project-1'))
      expect(queryByTestId('project-1')).toBeNull()
      expect(getByTestId(TABLE_TEST_ID)).not.toHaveTextContent('Testing Project Alpha')
    })
})
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: execute is not a function

      16 |   )
      17 |   const removeProject = async (project) => {
    > 18 |     await execute()
         |           ^
      19 |     updateProjects(project)
      20 |   }
      21 |
```

I understand that the problem is that I am not passing the correct mock for the component `RemoveProjectButton`. However, I have no idea how I can achieve this because `useAxios` is being called in different components, and it should have with different returns values. I have also tried using `mockImplementationOnce`, but it seems the component `Projects` gets rendered several times before rendering the component `RemoveProjectButton`, so I feel that I am like guessing the number of times I will have to use `mockImplementationOnce`.

Comment: Does the following work: `useAxios.mockReturnValueOnce(firscCall).mockReturnValueOnce(secondCall)`?

Comment: *guessing the number of times I will have to use mockImplementationOnce* - it's ok in this situation. The test becomes fragile but it's generally a good thing, if the test becomes red you know that it needs your intervention because underlying units were changed. The problem is that this is integration test because you're unable to isolate Projects and RemoveProjectButton. Multiple useAxios calls wouldn't be an issue if Enzyme and shallowRender were used for Projects.

Comment: @HMR, thanks for your comment. It doesn't work. I am still getting an error message saying `TypeError: execute is not a function`

Comment: @EstusFlask, thanks for your comment. I think I will take the approach suggested in Mirone's answer. I totally understand the fact of lack of isolation in both components. However, at least for now I prefer not using Enzyme but react testing library instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the approach suggested by **@Mirone's answer**, but I got another issue after the mocking issue was solved, so I will add my complete answer in case somebody else experiences the same:

```js
it('removes project in table when clicking on X', async () => {
  const executeMock = jest.fn()
  useAxios.mockImplementation((...args) => {
    // This mocking was inspired on Mirone's answer
    switch (args.length) {
      case 1:
        return [{
          data: projects,
          loading: false,
          error: null
        }]
      case 2:
        return [{}, executeMock]
      default: break
    }
  })
  const { getByTestId, findByTestId } = render(<Projects />)
  expect(getByTestId('project-table')).toHaveTextContent('Testing Project Alpha')
  fireEvent.click(getByTestId('project-1'))
  const table = await findByTestId('project-table')
  expect(table).not.toHaveTextContent('Testing Project Alpha')
})
```

After the mocking issue was solved, I was getting an error:

> Warning: An update to Projects inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

This was solved by adding:

```js
const table = await findByTestId('project-table')
```

The previous line was waiting until the element with `data-testid="project-table"` was re-rendered, but I got one more error:

> MutationObserver is not a constructor

I found [an issue on Github](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/477) that provided the solution for this. Briefly speaking, the problem is that CRA is not using the latest version of `jsdom`, so the solution was so install `jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen` as follows:

```sh
yarn add jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen --dev
```

and also to set it up in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen",
   ...
}
```

I hope my answer helps someone else who might experience the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just use [mockImplementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn) then you can return different value according to the params.

```js
useAxios.mockImplementation((...args) => {
  if (match1(args)) {
    return result1;
  }
  if (match2(args)) {
    return result2;
  }
  return result3;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helped make progress in my test .

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but I will validate the one I have added since it provides the exact solution for the problem I described. However, thank you so much for your help.